# Excel: How to count two ranges for duplicates ignoring blanks?

Tags: excel

I have the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B2: Z2, Sheet!B2: Z2))
```

to count the duplicates between two ranges in two sheets. However, I need it to ignore blank cells and only count duplicates within populated cells (number of populated cells differ row by row)

How can I do this?

Comment: The formula should work exactly the way you want it to. It ignores blanks.

Comment: Show your data (or markup data) if you don't mind.